# How to run a subquery in hive

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive

I have this query that I am trying to run in HIVE:

```
select transaction_date, count(total_distinct) from (
SELECT transaction_date, concat(subid,'**', itemid) as total_distinct
FROM TBL_1
group by transaction_date, subid,itemid
) group by transaction_date
```

What I am trying to do it get the distinct combination of subid and itemid, but I need the total count per day. When I run the query above, I get this error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 6:2 cannot recognize input near 'group' 'by' 'TRANSACTION_DATE' in subquery source
```

The query looks correct to me though. Has anyone encountered this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive requires subqueries to be aliased, so you need to specify a name for it:

```
select transaction_date, count(total_distinct) from (
SELECT transaction_date, concat(subid,'**', itemid) as total_distinct
FROM TBL_1
group by transaction_date, subid,itemid
) dummy  -- << note here
group by transaction_date
```

True, the error message is far from helpful.